# How to define multidimensional matrix with strings in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I wish to store strings in multidimensional array. I tried using `numpy` package along with following line:

```
    co_entity = np.zeros((5000,4))
```

However, I need to store strings later on. This matrix cannot be used to store strings as it has floats/int. I tried using list to store the strings but since the number of input is dynamic, I have to use multidimensional array with upper limit.

Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `object` type with `empty()` function like so

```
co_entity = np.empty((5000,4), dtype='object')
```

This will allow you to store a string in each of the elements generated.